# KeysPipe class return two times the object when called

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a little problem to display correctly the values of an object retrieved by calling a service.ts method. Actually, the object is displayed two times and I don't know why.

My KeysPipe class give me one empty object and then the full object I need
That's my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-api',
    template: `<h1>{{api}}</h1>
                  <br />
                  <table class="table">
                  <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Street</th>
                      <th>House number</th>
                      <th>Postal code</th>
                      <th>City</th>
                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>number</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>                              
                    <td *ngFor="let key of customers | keys ;">
                         {{ key.value }}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                      `,
    providers: [
        CustomerService
    ]
})

export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit
{
    api: string;
    public customers: Customer[];

    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService)
    {
        this.api = "API Customers";
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {

        this.customerService.getCustomer(3804).subscribe(result => this.customers = result);
    }
}

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(value)
    {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value)
        {
            keys.push({value: value[key]});
        }
        console.log(keys);
        return keys;
    }
}

[I have one empty object and then the object I need !! ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMTZt.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time, the pipe is executed, when Angular run change detection. Only after the first change detection method ngOnInit is called. It means that KeysPipe run, before component will get data from service.

You should add condition to KeysPipe, that return empty array or null, if argument will be null, f.e.:

```
transform(value: any) {
    let keys = [];
    if(value) {
        for (let key in value) {
            //some code
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have only one object but when i run the chrome developer tools, it show me on the <tr> tag of my ngfor an "&npsp &npsp &npsp &npsp &npsp &npsp &npsp" tag with value ... What's the problem and how can I remove this spaces ? ty